# git cannot commit after npm version patch

Tags: git, npm

I do `npm version patch` then `cat package.json` and see that version is changed. 
Then do `git add package.json` and then `git commit -m "new version"` but see

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

When I change version in package.json by hands then I can `git commit` as expected. But using `npm version patch` is faster. So how to commit after it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, according to the [documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version), it already creates a commit for you:

> If run in a git repo, it will also create a version commit and tag, and fail if the repo is not clean.

Comment: Is there any way to stop this default behavior? Annoyingness :P

Comment: yes, run the version command wih this flag: `npm --no-git-tag-version version`
see np.org for more info: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Comment: If you want to make sure that the commit as been automagically done, you can check the log like this `git log -n --oneline` (`n` as the number of last commits)